# A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type Residential Building

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, visual-studio-2013

I receive the following exception when trying to make an AJAX call. I have no idea what this is.

Here's the code for the controller:

```
public JsonResult getBldgInfo(string type, short stories, int size)
    {
        var info = from r in db.ResidentialBuildings
                   where r.type == type
                   && r.stories == stories
                   && r.size == size
                   select new { r };
        return Json(info, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Here's the AJAX call:

```
 $("#ResidentialBuildingSize").change(function () {
    infoHead = "infoHead";
    invisible = "invisible";
    type = $("#ResidentialBuildingType").val();
    stories = $("#ResidentialBuildingStories").val();
    size = $("#ResidentialBuildingSize").val();
    console.log(type);
    console.log(stories);
    console.log(size);
    url = "/ResidentialBuilding/getBldgInfo?type=" + type + "&stories=" + stories + "&size=" + size;
    console.log(url);
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            $("#titles").empty();
            $("#values").empty();
            $("#titles").append('<h5 class="' + infoHead + '">' + value.r.type + " (" + value.r.stories + ")" + '</h5>');
            $("#titles").append('<p>' + "Stories" + '</p>');
            $("#titles").append('<p>' + "Age" + '</p>');
            $("#titles").append('<p>' + "Size" + '</p>');
            $("#titles").append('<p>' + "Orientation" + '</p>');
            $("#titles").append('<p>' + "Shape" + '</p>');
            $("#titles").append('<p>' + "Floor Height" + '</p>');
            $("#titles").append('<p>' + "Foundation" + '</p>');
            $("#titles").append('<p>' + "Window Percent" + '</p>');
            $("#titles").append('<p>' + "Heating" + '</p>');
            $("#titles").append('<p>' + "Cooling" + '</p>');
            $("#values").append('<h5 class="' + infoHead + ' ' + invisible + '">' + '&nbsp;' + '</h5>');
            $("#values").append('<p><strong>' + value.r.stories + '</strong></p>');
            $("#values").append('<p><strong>' + value.r.age + '</strong></p>');
            $("#values").append('<p><strong>' + value.r.size + '</strong></p>');
            $("#values").append('<p><strong>' + value.r.orientation + '</strong></p>');
            $("#values").append('<p><strong>' + value.r.shape + '</strong></p>');
            $("#values").append('<p><strong>' + value.r.floorht + '</strong></p>');
            $("#values").append('<p><strong>' + value.r.foundation + '</strong></p>');
            $("#values").append('<p><strong>' + value.r.windowpercent + '</strong></p>');
            $("#values").append('<p><strong>' + value.r.heating + '</strong></p>');
            $("#values").append('<p><strong>' + value.r.cooling + '</strong></p>');
        });
    });
});

$("#info").click(function () {
    $("#bldgInfo").slideToggle('2000', 'linear');
});
```

Please do let me know if I am doing anything wrong. This exact code worked when I was working with a local database.

**UPDATE**

Here's the code for the ResidentialBuilding model.

```
namespace BIRDS.Models



public partial class ResidentialBuilding
{
    public ResidentialBuilding()
    {
        this.ResidentialDatas = new HashSet<ResidentialData>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public short stories { get; set; }
    public int size { get; set; }
    public string age { get; set; }
    public string orientation { get; set; }
    public string shape { get; set; }
    public int floorht { get; set; }
    public string foundation { get; set; }
    public int windowpercent { get; set; }
    public string heating { get; set; }
    public string cooling { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ResidentialData> ResidentialDatas { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show us the definition of the `ResidentialBuilding` class? I believe you have a reference to another object, that references back to ResidentialBuilding, causing the circular reference.

Comment: if the exact code worked with a local database.. then perhaps the answer is staring you right in the face ..meaning `Database connection and or Database table` check the config files and make sure that you have everything pointed correctly as well as configured correctly.. do you have an example of snippet of both .config file database settings, also make sure the `ResidentialBuildings` db context exist in regards to the table that it's suppose to read from and or reference..

Comment: The code for the model is added. Please do let me know.

Comment: Do you also need to pass the `ResidentialDatas` collection to the page?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have navigation properties in your model, so the serializer follows them and gets a reference to your model from a linked model, this process would continue infinitely if there was no circular reference detection mechanism.

To solve your problem, select only properties that you are interested in:

```
var info = from r in db.ResidentialBuildings
    where r.type == type
    && r.stories == stories
    && r.size == size
    select new { r.stories, r.age, r.size /* etc. */ };
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll venture that your `ResidentialData` class also has a reference back to the `ResidentialBuilding` class.  What happens when you serialize this to JSON, the `JavaScriptSerializer` sees the reference to the collection and begins to serialize the collection.  Within the `ResidentialData` class, it sees the reference back to the original `ResidentialBuilding` class - and it would continue to serialize further and further for forever.  What you need to do is have the serializer ignore either of the members - depending on your needs.

You can do this by adding a reference to the `System.Web.Extensions` assembly in your project.  From here, you would add a reference to the serialization class (`using System.Web.Script.Serialization;`).

Finally, you can use the [`ScriptIgnoreAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx) flag so it will no longer serialize the collection, and won't throw a circular reference.  The new class should look like this:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public partial class ResidentialBuilding
{
    public ResidentialBuilding()
    {
        this.ResidentialDatas = new HashSet<ResidentialData>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public short stories { get; set; }
    public int size { get; set; }
    public string age { get; set; }
    public string orientation { get; set; }
    public string shape { get; set; }
    public int floorht { get; set; }
    public string foundation { get; set; }
    public int windowpercent { get; set; }
    public string heating { get; set; }
    public string cooling { get; set; }

    [ScriptIgnoreAttribute]
    public virtual ICollection<ResidentialData> ResidentialDatas { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that your:

```
public virtual ICollection<ResidentialData> ResidentialDatas { get; set; }
```

Is and Entity Framework navigation property, and a ResidentialData class has a navigation property back to ResidentialBuilding.

You can use a DTO to get round this, perhaps using a library like AutoMapper to map between the types, ignoring or adding properties as you need them.